# angularjs + typeahead input field initial vaule

Tags: angularjs, initialization, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I have this directive, which is basicly wrapper for typeahead plugin from bootstrap. Everything is working like a charm. But now I have to set initial vaule in typeahead's input field. The value is passed as a string in attrs.init. But I don't know how to insert it into text field.

```
angular.module('rcApp')
  .directive('rcAutocomplete', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
    return {
      scope: {
        model: '@',
        search: '@',
        key: '@',
        show: '@',
        init: '@',
        ngModel: '='
      },
      template: '<input type="text">',
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        // inject model service
        var service = $injector.get(attrs.model);

        // define search function
        var searchFunction = attrs.search;

        // holds picked object id
        scope.id = 0;

        // holds objects that matched query, mapped by "show" value
        scope.map = {};

        element.on('focusout ac.itempicked', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.ngModel = scope.id;
          });
        });

        // launch typehead plugin
        element.typeahead(
          {
            source: function (query, process) {

              // clear cache
              scope.id = 0;
              scope.map = {};

              service[searchFunction](query).then(function (result) {

                var dataValues = [];

                var fieldsToShow = scope.show.split('|');

                $.each(result.data, function (index, dataItem) {

                  // generate key-show string
                  var valueHash = '';

                  for (var i = 0; i < fieldsToShow.length; i++) {
                    valueHash += dataItem[fieldsToShow[i]] + ' ';
                  }

                  valueHash = $.trim(valueHash);

                  // map results
                  scope.map[valueHash] = dataItem;
                  // prepare return strings
                  dataValues.push(valueHash);
                });

                // return content
                process(dataValues);
              });
            },
            updater: function (item) {
              if (typeof scope.key === 'undefined') {
                scope.id = scope.map[item];
              }
              else {
                scope.id = scope.map[item][scope.key];
              }

              element.trigger('ac.itempicked');

              return item;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    };
  }]);
```

** UPDATE **

Solution, that worked for me is adding code like this to link function:

```
// init value
if (typeof attrs.init !== 'undefined') {
   window.setTimeout(function () {
      element.val(attrs.init);
      scope.$apply();
   }, 10);
}
```

But still I don't quite understand why "element.val(attrs.init);" don't updated the view, and calling scope.$apply() did, but throw an "$digest already in progress" error. Wrapping it in window.setTimeout helped, but this also is a hack for me....

It's got to be a way to make it cleaner/simpler...

Comment: You might want to check the typeahead directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. It is fully-functional typeahead re-written as AngularJS directive so doesn't need jQuery / bootstrap CSS etc.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I think, it does'nt fit my demands. And the main reason is that I have to display (in field) other values than i want to store in a model. For example, I wan't it to show "Fiat 126p", and store its id "1" in the model. That's why I've written my own directive (based on bootstrap version, but i can always use anoter one). And it's working. Only problem is that I can't find way to put initial value(initial string, like "Fiat 126p"), before user starts typing.